# How to send popup messages to the device connected to my wifi network?

Tags: wifi

Is it possible to send some popup messages or sms/mms over wifi network?? If yes how to send.
My use case is to send some kind of popups to the devices that connects to my open wifi network. The popups could be anything like graphical advertisements or any information. 
Can anyone help me with my use case?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make a fake DNS server on your server or home computer and redirect the dns server address on your access point to your machine. Your dns server would then show your website with the advertisement. Then store a cookie on the guest machine, so the second time your DNS would forward it to the real website. You can ex. reset the cookie every 24h. Then every day the user would see your ads. Or make a website with a big button with the link to the real site.